# Alignment Problem with Datatable Header when use ScrollY

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatable, scroll

I have a problem with data table header alignment. All things will go fine until I did not use ScrollY.

On the page, I have a side navbar, that can be expanded. Now When I expand the side navbar and move the content area toward the right side, the table header goes out of the page.

```
1. Table:
 <table  class="flex-fill flex-grow-1 table table-striped table-hover table-bordered " id="data_table" style="background:red ;width: 100%">
         <thead>
           <tr>    
              <th>Header-1</th>
              <th>Header-2</th>
              <th>Header-3</th>
              <th>Header-4</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>             
           </tr>           
         </tbody>
        </table>


2. Script.

$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#data_table').DataTable( {
    paging: true,
    ordering:false,
    scrollY:315,
    scrollCollapse:true,
    scrollX:true
   });
});
```

html view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using css bootstrap?

Please try to use the following script

**Html**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="flex-fill flex-grow-1 table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="data_table" style="background:red ;width: 100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header-1</th>
        <th>Header-2</th>
        <th>Header-3</th>
        <th>Header-4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

Add the script below after datatable initiation

```
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

And the script will be like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $("#data_table").DataTable({
    paging: true,
    ordering: false,
    scrollY: 315,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scrollX: true
  });

  table.columns.adjust().draw();
});
```

example : [codepen](https://codepen.io/mocfaisal/pen/ZEePJLd)

Comment: I tried, what you suggested, but the problem is still the same.  Please see https://codepen.io/adiicmp/pen/abJMEdz

Now click on the check box. This is what i tried to explain. When Side menu collapsed and move the content area toward right, header will go out of page.

Comment: @Aditya if your datatables is not used FixedColumns, just removed ScrollY, and use tag div table-responsive. check this : https://codepen.io/mocfaisal/pen/xxqebaO

Comment: I have to use scrollY because I want to provide a fixed height to the data table and all the records will reflect in that particular fix height frame box. 
And WIthout Scroll Y, the user needs to scroll the page. That's why ScrollY is important.